# Simulation for conditional probabilty problem in python

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate a simple conditional probability problem. You hae two boxes. If you open A you have a 50% change of wining the prize, If you open B you have a 75% chance of winning. With some simple (bad) python I have tired
But the appending doesn't work. Any thoughts on a neater way of doing this?

```
import random
import numpy as np
def liveORdie(prob):
    #Takes an argument of the probability of survival
    live = 0
    for i in range(100):
        if random.random() <= prob*1.0:
            live =1
    return live

def simulate(n):
    trials = np.array([0])
    for i in range(n):
        if random.random() <= 0.5:
            np.append(trials,liveORdie(0.5))
            print(trials)
        else:
            np.append(trials,liveORdie(0.75))
    return(sum(trials)/n)


simulate(10)
```

Comment: Side note, you should not be using numpy arrays in loops then calling python methods on them. If you are not confident with numpy or python yet, I'd stick to just python regular lists for now.

Comment: The `for` loop in `liveORdie` keeps overwriting the `live` variable so it can only ever be 0 or 1, despite 100 trials (though almost guaranteed to always be 1)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the code tighter by using list comprehensions and numpy's array operations, like so:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def LiveOrDie():
    prob = 0.5 if random.random()<=0.5 else 0.75
    return np.sum(np.random.random(100)<=prob)

def simulate(n):
    trials = [LiveOrDie() for x in range(n)]
    return(sum(trials)/n)

Simulate(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` is a `list` operation; you're forcing it onto a `numpy` array, which is not the same thing.  Stick with a regular list, since  you're not using any extensions specific to an array.

```
def simulate(n):
    trials = []
    for i in range(n):
        if random.random() <= 0.5:
            trials.append(liveORdie(0.5))
```

Now look at your liveORdie routine.  I don't think this is what you want: you loop 100 times to produce a single integer ... and if any *one* of your trials comes up successful, you return a `1`.  Since you haven't provided documentation for your algorithms, I'm not *sure* what you want, but I suspect that it's a list of 100 trials, rather than the conjunction of all 100.  You need to `append` here, as well.

Better yet, run through a tutorial on *list comprehension*, and use those.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in `liveORdie()` (please consider [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions) will cause the probability of winning to increase: each pass of the loop has a `prop` chance of winning, and you give it 100 tries, so with 50% resp. 75% you are extremely likely to win.

Unless I really misunderstood the problem, you probably just want

```
def live_or_die(prob):
    return random.random() < prob
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that just reduces to:

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy.random import choice
from scipy.stats import bernoulli

def simulate(n):
  probs = choice([0.5, 0.75], n)
  return 1-mean(bernoulli.rvs((1-probs)**100))
```

which as others have pointed out will basically always return 1 — `0.5**100` is ~1e-30.